# Array Drops Object After Iteration

Tags: java

I'm adding objects to an array.  I can successfully add the first object, and loop through to the second object.  After I've added the second object, the array drops the second object when the method ends.

This is for a class so we limited to basic things we've learned.  What am I missing?

```
public class Assignment02Driver {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Item yourItem = new Item();
Item[] cargohold = new Item[1];
Item[] holdThis = new Item[1];
int numberOItems = 0;
int index = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Assignment02Driver();
}

public Assignment02Driver() {

System.out.println("Welcome to the BlackStar Cargo Hold interface.");
System.out.println("Please select a number from the options below");
System.out.println("");

while (true) {
    // Give the user a list of their options
        System.out.println("1: Add an item to the cargo hold.");

        // Get the user input
        int userChoice = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        switch (userChoice) {
    case 1:
                addItem(cargohold);
                break;
 // Other Stuff


 // Add Item Method
private void addItem(Item cargohold[]) {
    Item cargo = new Item();
    while (numberOItems > 10) {
        System.out.println("We're too good at pirating. Go remove some loot.");
    }

    // Name item
    System.out.println("What item did you loot?"); // Hey you!
    String item = input.nextLine(); // What item was gained
    cargo.setName(item); // Save in position 1 of array        

    // Item weight
    System.out.println("What is its weight in kilograms?");
    double mass = input.nextDouble();
    cargo.setWeight(mass);

    // Item value

    // Item durability

    // Item ID
```

I think the problem is in here, but I don't know how to fix it:

```
    // Resize the array and add the item to it
    if (numberOItems == cargohold.length) {
        Item[] holdThis = new Item[cargohold.length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOItems; i++) {
                holdThis[i] = cargohold[i];
    }
            cargohold = holdThis;

    }
    cargohold[numberOItems] = cargo;

    // Add item to count
    numberOItems++;
}
```

Right after it exists this method, the second Item is removed/lost from the array.  If I try to add another item, I get an out of bounds error.

Comment: Probably this:`cargohold = holdThis;` is the problem. hint:`this`

Comment: I didn't even realize I'd gotten rid of that.  Thank you.  You = Hero.